# UICollectionView prefetching doesn't work with dynamic cell sizing

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, uicollectionview

I couldn't actually see this in any documentation but if you implement `UICollectionViewDataSourcePrefetching` and have dynamically sized cells:

```
    collectionView.delegate = self
    collectionView.dataSource = self
    collectionView.prefetchDataSource = self
    layout.itemSize = UICollectionViewFlowLayout.automaticSize
    layout.estimatedItemSize = UICollectionViewFlowLayout.automaticSize
```

`collectionView prefetchItemsAt` *does not work*.  If you comment out the lines with `automaticSize` in them, *it will work*.  However, that doesn't help when you need dynamically sized cells.

Anyone found a work around for this?  Otherwise i'll just have to use:

`collectionView willDisplay forItemAt`

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: If i recall correctly i _think_ the answer just is: you can't. - you have to use `collectionView willDisplay forItemAt`

Comment: This is the same route I took, I just wished there was a way to use prefetching with dynamic sized cells :-P